# How can I stop these various aspects of my display from glitching up when I resume from hibernate (uswsusp)?

Tags: suspend, lightdm, hibernate, tuxonice

I have Ubuntu Mate Xenial, but this was happening before I upgraded from Wily too. I'm running an HP Envy M6.

My problem is:

I've installed uswsusp to save power, and I regularly hibernate the computer with it. But when I resume from hibernation, I often end up with screen glitches. Like:

- Some letters missing (the most common and noticeable). That is, application windows will be brought up, but a few characters won't be shown, leaving blank spaces. This includes the login prompt window and sometimes the terminal, though applications themselves, like Chrome, usually seem to display properly.
- Cursor missing, though everything functions as though it were there.
- Unpredictable choice of which greeter window will be shown. I've forgotten what I used to do it, but I set a custom login prompt theme, and now I'll sometimes get that, and sometimes the default - though most often the default.
- And even unpredictable choice of how long GRUB waits before choosing the top choice on the menu. A while ago I used a GRUB customizer GUI to set that to 2 seconds, but now the computer more often counts down from 30 seconds when I resume.

When I was installing a hibernation module, I first tried tuxonice, but ended up with scary errors (I'm fairly new to Ubuntu). One error resulted in no desktop environment, and I had to revert the last file I'd changed through `vim`; I was lucky I remembered its path. After that I gave up on tuxonice, but I have a suspicion that remnants of it might still be lurking.

I've been able to get around the issue by running `sudo service lightdm restart`, a solution I found somewhere else, but it's annoying to have to log back on and restart all my programs so often when I resume.

I seem to recall this happening after resuming from simple sleep sometimes too, but it hasn't happened recently. If it does, I'll update this question.

Tried looking for log files, but they all seem to be from months ago, and some of them don't want to open for me. If you tell me the answer is probably in one of those, I'll put some more effort into getting it to open.

Thanks for any help. I'd love to get this figured out - whether by fixing uswsusp or, conceivably, trying again with tuxonice - so I can feel confident in Ubuntu and clear up some room by emptying out my Windows partition.